# Do I need to sanitize the user input Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, xss, sql-injection

I am using Laravel 4 with Eloquent.
When I get the user input I just use `$name=Input::get('name')` and then I do `$a->name=$name;`

I don't know if the function `Input::get` protect me from SQL Injection and XSS. If it does not, what do I have to do to sanitize the input?

And, when I show the value in my view, shall I use `{{$a}}` or `{{{$a}}}`

Comment: In addition to the other answers, in case you decide to use something like new Something(Input::all()) make sure to specify the $fillable fields in the Something model, in order to protect against mass assignment. Not strictly pertaining to your questions, but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Eloquent ORM uses PDO's parameter binding, so SQL injection is not something you should worry about. When you're working with raw SQL, you should be using parameter binding as well.

Input::get() does not filter anything.

Double curly braces (triple in the discontinued versions) do the same as e() and HTML::entities(). All of them call htmlspecialchars with UTF-8 support:

```
htmlspecialchars($your_string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Comment: If I use {{{ to show it, should I use also htmlentities when saving the information?

Comment: Escape output, not input.

Comment: There's no need to alter data unless you actually use it. Filter input, escape output.

Comment: It should be pointed out that Laravel provides raw sql query support which isn't protected from injection at all.   So there is always the chance that someone may build a site with some raw queries that do need manual cleaning.

Answer (score 5):

You should use  `{{{$a}}}` because for example Input can has HTML tag. Laravel won't filter it.

To avoid SQL injection you should use bind your parameters running queries like:

```
$var = 1;
$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = ?', array($var));
```

and not:

```
$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = '.$var);
```

Comment: So I should use htmlentities or something like that? What does Input::get filter?

Comment: @Fylux So far as I know it's interface to getting POST, GET and so on data. It trims data but doesn't filter it, so when displaying you should use triple bracing - this way `htmlentities` function is run on variable value

Comment: If I use {{{ to show it, should I use also htmlentities when saving the information?

Comment: @Fylux No, using `{{{` Laravel will do it for you

Comment: But is there any problem if I have a corrupted input saved in my db?

Comment: @Fylux what do you mean? Always there might be some problem and running htmlentities or {{{ in theory should solve this problem

Comment: I mean, if would be better to do both things, use htmlentities and {{{

Comment: And about you comment, I guess I won't have problem with binding parameters because I use Eloquent.

Comment: Don't use `DB::select(...)`. Better use models `User::find($id)`.

Answer (score -1):

This returns sanitized string enclosed within quotes for safe use in a SQL query:

```
$safe_string = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($unsafe_string);
```

Comment: Not a single reason to use this function